# Can Eigen be used also for 1-vectors (scalars)?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am writing some routine which is formally identical for 2-vectors and also for scalars. I would like to write is as a template for `Eigen::Matrix<double,N,1>`, instantiating it for N=2 or N=1 (for scalars, wrapping scalar `double d` as `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double,1,1>>(&d)`.

Is Eigen designed with that special case in mind? Is it going to be efficient, e.g. internally calling `abs(v1)` for `Eigen::Matrix<double,1,1>::norm()`, `v1*v1` for `squaredNorm()` or `copysign(1,v1)` for `normalized()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit specializations for `size=1`, but thanks to explicit unrollers, most expression will generate scalar code. For instance, `squaredNorm()` will generate `x*x`, but `norm` will generate `sqrt(x*x)`. Same for `normalized()`.

Comment: Thanks! (I have to write more, says SO :) So: maybe a potentially useful optimization).